# Are there regular languages between every two non-regular languages?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I have a question regarding regular languages. Given that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are non-regular languages, can a regular language $L$ exist so it is a subset of $L_2$ and $L_1$ subset of $L$?

To be more specific:

$\qquad L_1 \subset L \subset L_2$

for $L_1, L_2$ non-regular Languages.

Comment: Do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$? Do we know $L_1 \subseteq L_2$? And: What have to tried, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Given any sets $A, B, C$ we have $A \cap C \subset C \subset B \cup C$.

Comment: Thx for you answer you really guided to the solution!

Comment: Might be interesting to give languages $A \cap C, B \cup C, C$ that fulfill the desired properties.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesired posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/).